# Как грамотно вставить название таблицы из переменной в SQL-запрос? PHP/PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Забиндить невозможно, а аналогов `mysql_real_escape_string()` у PDO нет. Будет ли правильно использовать `PDO::quote()` ?

```
"SELECT * FROM" . $pdo->quote( $table ) .";
```

Или как тогда поступать в этом случае?

Comment: Неправильно написал. Ну, думаю, смысл моего вопроса ясен и без этого.

Comment: Кажется, я придумал. Можно просто после коннекта к бд сохранить в глобальной переменной массив всех таблиц, создать функцию, которая бы проверяла значение в переменной, которая содержит предполагаемую таблицу, с этим массивом. Медленно, но 100% безопасно.

Comment: какая логика процесса то? вы имя таблицы от пользователя получаете что ли? или по какой причине вы в своем коде не знаете из какой таблицы данные брать?

Comment: `quote` один фиг не то. идентификаторы должны заключаться в обратные кавычки, а не в простые. И если надо проверить корректность вводимых имен таблиц, то проверка по готовому перечню даст эффективный и гибкий подход. не знаю, что вы там нашли медленного.

Comment: как будто mysql_real_escape_string() могла бы хоть чем-то помочь..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Поскольку через подготовленные выражения можно подставлять только *данные*, то для имен полей и таблиц остается только фильтрация через **белый список** - то есть проверка по явно прописанному в коде списку разрешенных значений.

#### Использование ORM

Вариантов реализации может быть много, один из них предложен автором в комментариях - считать из БД все названия таблиц и запомнить их. Это, в принципе, может сработать. Некоторые фреймворки даже кэшируют эту информацию (например Yii). В случае с продвинутыми ORM названия полей-таблиц берутся из свойств соответствующего класса, опять же, прописанные вручную.

#### Фильтрация через белый список

Но если мы колупаемся по-старинке, выполняя запросы напрямую через PDO, то проще всего будет прописать доступные варианты прямо перед использованием, тем более что таких случаев не должно быть много - иначе у нас явные проблемы с проектированием.

Плюс надо не забыть оформить имя поля или таблицы в соответствии с синтаксисом базы данных. Например, для mysql это будет заключение значения в backtick-и.

В итоге получаем примерно такой код:

```
if (!in_array($table, ["user","product","catalog"]));
{
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Invalid table name!");
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `$table` WHERE foo = ?" // далее как обычно
```

#### Выборка одного поля

В случае, если нам надо выбрать из таблицы только одно поле (и в ней нет очень тяжелых полей), можно выбрать все, а вернуть только нужное

```
function get_column($db, $column, $id) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?');
    $stmt->execute([$id]));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $res[$column];
}
```

#### Динамическое составление запросов INSERT/UPDATE

Куда более частой является ситуация, когда нам надо выполнить запрос UPDATE динамически, если имена полей приходят, допустим, из $_POST. Принцип остается тем же:

```
/ список допустимых значений
$allowed = ["name","surname","email"];

// инициализация массива для значений
$params = [];

// инициализация строки с парами `fieldname` = :placeholder
$setStr = "";

// цикл по разрешенным полям
foreach ($allowed as $key)
{
    if (isset($_POST[$key]) && $key != "id")
    {
        $setStr .= " `$key` = ?,";
        $params[] = $_POST[$key];
    }
}
$setStr = rtrim($setStr, ",");

$params[] = $_POST['id'];
$pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET $setStr WHERE id = ?")->execute($params);
```

#### Что делать нельзя

В заключение рассмотрим пару примеров того, что делать ни в коем случае **нельзя:**

- это очевидно, но тем не менее: **нельзя подставлять имя поля в запрос напрямую без всякой обработки**. Да, понятно что лень, и что данные "100% безопасные, мамой клянус!". Важно понимать, что это сейчас у вас данные безопасные, и вы об этом знаете. Но со временем на проект могут прийти другие люди, которые не знают какие данные можно передавать, а какие нельзя. **Код должен быть безопасным при любых вариантах использования**.
- mysql_real_escape_string. многие поколения пхп кодеров считали и считают, что эта функция служит для защиты от неких инъекций. С такой точки зрения ее применение, конечно, оправдано. Но если однажды открыть для себя реальное предназначение этой функции, то станет ясно, что она здесь нужна как хипстеру андроид. Можно даже посмотреть [действующий пример SQL инъекции](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example#escaping), которой эта, как и любая другая функция искейпинга **строк**, не может помешать ни в малейшей степени.
- PDO::quote(). Уже **гораздо** лучше. В отличие от предыдущего варианта, который пройдет незамеченным, а потом пропустит инъекцию, quote() вызовет ошибку немедленно, поскольку выбирать данные из *строки* БД еще не научились - им нужно название таблицы.
  Некоторое время назад в комментариях к этой функции в мануале висел комментарий, причем с кучей положительных оценок, предлагавший оторвать от полученного значения добавленные к нему кавычки. Я посоветовал вместо этого оторвать руки предложившему, но сошлись на том, что оторвут только его комментарий. В итоге я написал свой, с объяснениями, как делать правильно.

Comment: фига, кто там минусовать то решил, не осилили много букв, или сложным слогом написано?

Answer (score -2):

```
 SELECT * FROM '".$tablevariable."' where ...
```

Вот по полному

```
 mysqli_query($dblink, " SELECT * FROM '".$tablevariable."' ");
```

Comment: Если вы не заметили, то вопрос про PDO.

Comment: Если вы не заметили, то вопрос как **грамотно** вставить название таблицы.