# Переменная в запросе ДБ

Tags: php, sql

Делаю мультиязчность для сайта, есть запрос к дб:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT id, title, date, short_content, thumbnail, cat, status FROM news ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10");
```

Надо добавить переменную с ключом языка +нижнее подчеркивание + news. Не могу соорудить запрос. Кто может, помогите. В итоге должно быть ru_news, en_news

```
$locale = trim(strip_tags($locale));
        echo $locale;
        $db = Db::getConnection();
        $newsList = array();
        $result = $db->query("SELECT id, title, date, short_content, thumbnail, cat, status FROM `".$locale."`_news ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10");
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/745907/186083 а так у вас апострофы не там стоят.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное нужно так:

```
"SELECT id, title, date, short_content, thumbnail, cat, status 
FROM `".$locale."_news` 
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 10"
```

В двойных кавычках, емнип, можно было так:

```
"SELECT id, title, date, short_content, thumbnail, cat, status 
FROM `{$locale}_news` 
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 10"
```

---

Ошибка была в

```
`".$locale."`_news
            ^----
```

а нужно

```
`".$locale."_news`
                 ^----
```

---

Как правильно отметили в комментарии: посмотрите как правильно делать, когда хотите добавить пользовательскую подстановку в качестве выборки имени таблицы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/745907/191482  (про белый список)...

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: @AnryReese если помогло - то можно ткнуть на галочку рядом с ответом ;-)

Comment: Извини, пока не разобрался в функциях сайта. Хотел репу поднять,но там ограниение