# Не работает запрос на PDO

Tags: php, pdo

```
$params = ['fields_sort' =>'title'];
$q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE parent = 693 ORDER BY :fields_sort ASC",$params);
```

Запрос работает, но без учета сортировки в параметрах `$params`, поле `title` в БД имеется, в чем ошибка?

Comment: В том что нельзя использовать подготовленные выражения для названий полей, таблиц и т.д.

Comment: тут нет смысла в подготовленных выражениях. мало того что имена полей в целом не могут быть параметреризованы, а во вторых, какой в этом смысл? у вас же там не кастомный ввод пользователя? иначе введет имя несуществующего поля и конец.  Проверьте название поля по белому списку и подставляйте в запрос без всякой параметризации.

Comment: @teran, из массива будут приходить параметры по которым нужно сортировать

Comment: @u_mulder, как решить это?

Comment: Белый список - ваш лучший вариант.

Comment: @ArchDemon, есть вариант где не нужно переделывать логику всего сайта из-за одного примера?

Comment: Везде, где есть параметризация по именам таблиц и полей нужен белый список. Количество переделок зависит от текущей архитектуры вашего приложения. Мне через экран этого не увидеть.

Comment: @ArchDemon, есть примеры где это реализовывается с подготовительными запросами?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745544/Как-грамотно-вставить-название-таблицы-из-переменной-в-sql-запрос-php-pdo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Как грамотно вставить название таблицы из переменной в SQL-запрос? PHP/PDO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745544/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2-sql-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-php-pdo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете параметризовать имена полей в запросах. вам следует реализовать проверку параметров сортировки (имен столбцов) по белому списку.
В простейшем случае будет что-то наподобие следующего.

```
$allow = ['title', 'id', 'pub_date'];
$sort = ['pub_date', 'title'];              // получили откуда-то параметры сортировки
$order = array_intersect($orderBy, $allow); // проверили, что допустимо
$orderBy =  implode(',', $order);           // подготовили для подстановки в запрос 

$db->query("SELECT ... ORDER BY $orderBy");
```

Comment: немного не так сделал, но концепция та же  $arr = [
            'sort-new'=> 'id',
            'sort-asc'=> 'price',
            'sort-Alfavit'=> 'title',
        ];
        $param = $_GET['sort'];  
SELECT * FROM products WHERE parent = 693 ORDER BY ". $arr[$param] ." ASC"

Comment: если забиндить нельзя, то как в PDO экранировать?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй вот так:

```
$fields_sort = "title";
$q = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE parent = 693 ORDER BY :fields_sort ASC");

$q->bindParam(":fields_sort",$fields_sort,PDO::PARAM_STR);

$q->execute();
```

https://webzone.kz/publication/php-pdo